How to choose a loss function and how to calculate the loss for Text Generation in Generative AI?
For the classification problems, what loss functions can I choose ?
For the translation problem how do I decide whether the translation is good and how to choose a loss function?
And what about the question and answer problem ?

For classification, you use binary cross-entropy if it's binary classification or categorical-cross entropy if it's multiclass-classification. In both cases, you compute the loss against the true class labels.
For text generation, including translation, you use categorical cross-entropy against the target sequence.
For question-answering (QA), it depends if it's extractive QA or generative QA. If it's extractive, you compute the categorical cross-entropy against the marks of start and end of the answer within the text. If it's generative, you compute the categorical cross-entropy against the expected output sequence.

So in a nutshell, it is categorical cross-entropy, right ?

Yes, except for binary classification, where you should use binary cross-entropy.

@Qiulang did the answer solve the doubt from your question? If so, please consider marking it as correct (see the help center). If not, please leave a comment describing what is not clear or why you think it's not correct.

Sorry I have already upvoted but I did not accept your answer because I am new to this area so I am not sure if cross-entropy is the "only" loss function I can choose. I need to study more about it before I can accept your answer.
